# Samsung Portable SSD t3 2TB drive only shows 250GB capacity

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd, external-disk, disk-format

I am running Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6. My 2TB Samsung T3 only shows 250GB Capacity. I have installed the activation software from: http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/portable.html

I have formatted the drive using all available options under Disk Utility.

For an $800.00 hard drive that only has 1/8th of it's advertised capacity, this has turned out to be an *enormous* waste of money.

Comment: Can you add screenshots of Disk Utility with the physical disk selected and with the partition selected? Also the output from `diskutil list` would also be useful

Comment: The activation software is if you want encryption.  In addition to grgarsides request, also tripple check your packaging because Samsung does in fact make a 250GB model per their [specs\(http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/downloads/document/T3_Brochure_Final.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I spoke with Samsung today support today: They said I had been sold a "Tampered Model". Amazon.com did honor the request to return the item even though it was well outside the 30 day window for returns.